# Change string place android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I've got:

```
txtListChild.setText(PreferenceConnector.readString(_context,
                PreferenceConnector.COUNTRYSYMBOL, " $") +
                offerAmt /*+ " " + this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)*/);
```

Which is giving for example **PLN50**. How to change it, to get **50 PLN**?

Please help me guys!

Answer (score 2):

Change the order in which the `String`s are concatenated:

```
txtListChild.setText(offerAmt +" "+ PreferenceConnector.readString(_context,
                                      PreferenceConnector.COUNTRYSYMBOL, "$"))
```